# Dependent NativeSelect?

Tags: vaadin

I am building a form with two-dropdown (`NativeSelect`) , with second `NativeSelect` dependent on the first `NativeSelect` . Just like when selecting a State , and 'ZIP' shows its containing zip codes.

I searched but cannot find such example . This is my screen , it doesn't work. The second `NativeSelect` seems changing when user select the first `NativeSelect`, but I cannot dropdown the second `NativeSelect`.

[image]

This is initial state.

[image]

When user select 'company1' from the 'Company' dropdown

[image]

The 'entry' select is changed

But I cannot dropdown it.

Here is my code :

```
public SampleForm(Supplier<List<Company>> companySupplier , EntryDao entryDao) {
    this.companySupplier = companySupplier;
    this.entryDao = entryDao;

    setCompanySupplier(companySupplier);
  }

  public void setCompanySupplier(Supplier<List<Company>> companySupplier ) {
    this.companySupplier = companySupplier;
    companySupplier.get().forEach(company -> {
      companySelect.addItem(company);
      companySelect.setItemCaption(company, "[" + company.getId() + "] " + company.getName());
    });
    companySelect.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    companySelect.setMultiSelect(false);

    companySelect.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
      Company company = (Company) event.getProperty().getValue();
      logger.info("loading entries from company : {} " , company);
      setEntryList(entryDao.findByCompany(company));
    });
  }

  public void setEntryList(List<Entry> entryList) {
    entrySelect.removeAllItems();

    logger.info("entryList size = {}" , entryList.size());
    entryList.forEach(entry -> {
      entrySelect.addItem(entry);
      entrySelect.setItemCaption(entry , entry.toString());
    });

    entrySelect.setImmediate(true);

    entrySelect.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    entrySelect.setMultiSelect(false);
    entrySelect.setEnabled(true);
  }

  @Override
  protected Component createContent() {
    return new MVerticalLayout(
      new MFormLayout(companySelect , entrySelect , enabled)
        .withMargin(false) , getToolbar()
    ).withMargin(new MMarginInfo(false , true));
  }
```

My algorithm is simple : when user clicks the `companySelect` , the `addValueChangeListener` will load dependent entries (belonging to the company) , and set to the `entrySelect` .

But I don't know why it doesn't work.

Did I miss anything ? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the second popup is populated with values?

Comment: Check your `Entry` class. Does it implement `equals` and `hashCode` properly? Maybe post the code.

Comment: to @steffen-harbich . I am sure Entry implements equals and hashCode.

Comment: to @andré-schild , I am sure the second popup is populated with values. (I add logs , and it did show )

Comment: Another try would be to use the build-in layouts temporarily for test. Code seems to be fine. Without the code for Entry I won't be able to reproduce the issue, though.